# larger map marker in Overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I add a larger map marker image to an Overlay?  I'm using KMLLayer and the icon url is inside my KML file.  Google Maps appears to scale it down when i link to the larger icon.

I tried the  inside the KML but that didn't have any effect on the size of the image or something else is overriding it.

I believe it forces it to 32x32, but I need one at least twice that for a touch screen/kiosk app.  My icon is 64x64.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: How complex is your KML?  If you don't need to use KmlLayer, you could try rendering it with the kmz branch of [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) (or if you can post your KML, or a link to it, and the icon you are attempting to render is publicly available, I can show you what it will look like).

Comment: KML Layers are basically just placemarks. Here is one of the smaller ones http://www.doubletaketech.net/sapphire/Rigs.kml .  Any icon larger than 64x64 would be good for testing.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a KMZ file with those icons in it or publicly accessible versions of the icons?  Of could you create a KML file that uses publicly available icons (with an absolute URL)?  Do you need to display many more Placemarks than in that file (~32)?

Comment: smaller icon http://www.doubletaketech.net/sapphire/assets/redDown.png or larger one for testing http://www.doubletaketech.net/sapphire/assets/redUp.png

Comment: in this file, just 32.  in my other file of Refineries there are 100 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), the kmz branch, your icons are displayed full size (if you change the `<scale>0</scale>` to `<scale>1</scale>`.

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/doubletaketech_net_RigsB.kml

geoxml3 parses the KML in the client and renders the markers as native Google Maps API v3 markers.  For large numbers, KmlLayer is a better option, as it is rendered as tiles, but it doesn't seem to render markers at their native size, and it doesn't [support the scale tag](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps)

It also looks like you have the `<hotspot>` defined incorrectly:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/doubletaketech_net_RigsC.kml

Comment: Thanks for the great tip and taking the time to make the example. I'll give geoxml3 a try.  I do like the KMLLayer, so hopefully Google Maps will support scale at some point.